# What has changed in angularjs 1.1.5 to 1.2.0, that fixes IE 10 bug?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was having display issues w/ angular data not displaying in IE 10 unless I re-sized the web browser or tabbed from one field to another.

Upgrading angular to 1.2 from 1.1.5 did the trick but I'd like to know where I can see the version changes so I can narrow down where in my code things were failing.

I looked in [the api docs for angular](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api) but that doesn't tell me the difference between 1.1.5 & 1.2.0.

Can someone tell me where I can find what was changed between these two versions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the AngularJs ***v1.2.0-rc.3*** and earlier changelog at: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0/CHANGELOG.md

If you want to see the ***v1.2.0 timely-delivery (2013-11-08)*** you need to search it in all the changelog document: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

or tag by v1.2.1: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.1/CHANGELOG.md

---

As well you can see all the commits filtering by something like this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/compare/v1.1.5...v1.2.0

> NOTE: This only show the recent commits limited by 250 rows. So play
>   with the filter to get all the commits :D